# R How to reshape matrix using value in a column

Tags: r, reshape

I have matrix like this:

```
ID     Count
1      2
2      3
3      2
```

I want to create a matrix in which the number of rows for an `ID` equals the value of `Count` while adding a new column containing the index for each row within the `ID` value. For the matrix above, the result should be:

```
ID   Index
1    1
1    2
2    1
2    2
2    3
3    1
3    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple case you can just use `rep` and `sequence`.

```
ID=c(1,2,3)
Count=c(2,3,2)
cbind(ID=rep(ID, Count), Index=sequence(Count))
#     ID Index
#[1,]  1     1
#[2,]  1     2
#[3,]  2     1
#[4,]  2     2
#[5,]  2     3
#[6,]  3     1
#[7,]  3     2
```

Comment: I thought they asked for a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
          group_by(ID) %>% 
          nest() %>% 
          mutate(data=map(data,~seq_along(1:.x$Count))) %>% 
          unnest(data)
```

Output

```
     ID  data
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     2     1
4     2     2
5     2     3
6     3     1
7     3     2
```

Comment: This answer works too. I picked the answer above because it showed up first. Thanks for the quick response yesterday.